# How to Configure Magento 2 Security Scan?

Tags: magento2, security, security-scan-tool

Can anyone please explain STEP-BY-STEP PROCESS TO CONFIGURE MAGENTO 2 SECURITY SCAN?

Thanks

Comment: This is the step by step guide https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-security-scan-in-magento-2.html

Comment: See the steps of security scan into this https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/magento/security-scan.html